# Update and left outer join statements

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql

I have two tabels with a relation and I want to update a field in table A. Is it possible to combine update and join in the same query? I googled it but didnt find any working solution?

```
UPDATE md SET md.status = '3' 
FROM pd_mounting_details AS md 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_order_ecolid AS oe ON md.order_data = oe.id
```

I'm using MS SQL

Comment: The addition of that code indicates an error, what are you CROSS joining to?

Comment: @JohnH Sorry, the cross join where not ment to be there, visual studio adds that automaticly for some reason..

Comment: Please accept an answer...

Answer (score 76):

```
UPDATE
       t 
SET 
       t.Column1=100
FROM 
       myTableA t 
LEFT JOIN 
       myTableB t2 
ON 
       t2.ID=t.ID
```

Replace `myTableA` with your table name and replace `Column1` with your column name.

After this simply LEFT JOIN to tableB.  `t` in this case is just an alias for `myTableA`. `t2` is an alias for your joined table, in my example that is `myTableB`.  If you don't like using `t` or `t2` use any alias name you prefer - it doesn't matter - I just happen to like using those.

Comment: OK, thats about what i tried: Like this: `UPDATE md SET md.status = '3' FROM pd_mounting_details AS md LEFT JOIN pd_order_ecolid AS oe ON md.order_data = oe.id`

Comment: @Evilaid - I've added this code to the question. It will help to answer it.

Comment: @Evailaid as long as order_data is the same type of id from oe than I see no issue.

Comment: Should it be pd_mounting_details (underscore added)? Also note that if you are using '3' and not a value from pd_order_ecolid, this is the same as updating without a join. Perhaps you're either looking to use an inner join or a "WHERE oe.<non-nullable column> IS NOT NULL?

Comment: @JonH I tried to execute the query from visual studio and i get a warning saying: Column or expression 'status' cannot be updated. and after that i get an execution error saying: invalid object name 'md'

Comment: @Phil Helmer Yes thats right, im using underscore so the name och the table is "pd_mounting_details" The "status" column is of the type tinyint. Now im just tesing but you are right´, im using WHERE so it should look somting like this
`UPDATE    md
SET              md.status = 3
FROM         pd_mounting_details AS md INNER JOIN
                      pd_order_ecolid AS oe ON md.order_data = oe.idWHERE     (oe.id = 98)`

Comment: Assuming you have a space between "oe.id" and "WHERE", does that run successfully or give an error?

Comment: @Phil Helmer
 Yes i got the space ;) BUt still it doesnt run! Just the sam error: Column or expression 'status' cannot be updated. And then follows:  invalid object name 'md'

Comment: Strange i cant get it to work but when i try to run the query from SQL server management studio it works!

Comment: Please add to your original question to include your Visual Studio details (version, project type, the context in which you're running the query/code, etc.) This is not a T-SQL issue.

Comment: The outer joined version is pointless because every row will get updated anyway. The inner joined version is unnecessary - a EXISTS subquery achieves the same thing (and unlike the buggy join syntax, EXISTS is standard SQL.)

Answer (score 10):

If what you need is UPDATE from SELECT statement you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE suppliers    
SET city = (SELECT customers.city FROM customers

WHERE customers.customer_name = suppliers.supplier_name)
```

Answer (score 9):

In mysql the `SET` clause needs to come *after* the `JOIN`. Example:

```
UPDATE e
    LEFT JOIN a ON a.id = e.aid
    SET e.id = 2
    WHERE  
        e.type = 'user' AND
        a.country = 'US';
```

Answer (score 8):

Just another example where the value of a column from table 1 is inserted into a column in table 2:

```
UPDATE  Address
SET     Phone1 = sp.Phone
FROM    Address ad LEFT JOIN Speaker sp
ON      sp.AddressID = ad.ID
WHERE   sp.Phone <> ''
```

Answer (score 5):

The Left join in this query is pointless:

```
UPDATE md SET md.status = '3' 
FROM pd_mounting_details AS md 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_order_ecolid AS oe ON md.order_data = oe.id
```

It would update all rows of `pd_mounting_details`, whether or not a matching row exists in `pd_order_ecolid`. If you wanted to only update matching rows, it should be an inner join.

If you want to apply some condition based on the join occurring or not, you need to add a `WHERE` clause and/or a `CASE` expression in your `SET` clause.